# php Извлечь значение внутри скобок

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть стока:
`$size = "3.80 GB  (4075743232 Bytes)"`
Нужно извлечь только `4075743232` из скобок, и нужно понимать, что значения до скобок и внутри всегда разные.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

наиболее просто это решить регуляркой. Где то так

```
<?php
$re = '/\((\d+)[^)]+\)/';
$str = '3.80 GB  (4075743232 Bytes)';

if (preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches)) {
  print_r ($matches);
} else {
    print "ups";
}
```

Comment: Чуть упрощённый вариант: https://repl.it/EWCZ.

Comment: $pattern = '/(?<=\()\d+/';